# Allow a Spring REST method to call an asynchronous method and not wait for a response

Tags: spring, rest, asynchronous

Let's say I have a method `foo()` that takes approximately 30 minutes to execute in the back end, every night, at 3AM.

In a traditional sense, we could use Spring Scheduler and a cron annotation:

```
@Scheduled(cron = "0 0 3 ? * *")
public void foo() {
    ...
}
```

Unfortunately, this solution is not available to me due to reservations of the project lead on using Spring Scheduler over an enterprise scheduling tool.

In this case, what we have is the scheduling tool hitting a REST endpoint of the following method.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/foo", method = RequestMethod.Post)
public ResponseEntity<Boolean> doFoo() {
    foo(); //goal is to make this not hold up the return statement

    return ResponseEntity.ok(true);
}
```

Is there a way to make foo execute asynchronously without waiting for a completable future? `foo()` should continue off on its own for however long it needs, and the curl response should be almost immediate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to make `foo()` execute asynchronously without waiting for a completable future?

You could define the `foo()` method in a Spring Bean. As you don't seem to be interested in the any return value, you can use `void` as return type. Then annotate `foo()` with [`@Async`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/Async.html):

```java
@Service
public class FooService {

    @Async
    public void foo() {
        ...
    }
}
```

You also need to ensure that you have [`@EnableAsync`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/EnableAsync.html) in a configuration class:

```java
@EnableAsync
@Configuration
public class AsyncConfig {

}
```

Then you can invoke `foo()` from a controller method:

```java
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@RequestMapping(value = "/foo")
public class FooController {

    private final FooService fooService;

    @PostMapping
    public ResponseEntity<Boolean> doFoo() {
        fooService.foo();
        return ResponseEntity.ok(true);
    }
}
```

And, in case you need, you can also invoke `foo()` from `@Scheduled`-annotated method:

```java
@Scheduled(cron = "0 0 3 ? * *")
public void foo() {
    fooService.foo();
}
```

---

Let me just highlight that [`202`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.3.3) would be a more accurate status code than [`200`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.3.1) for this situation:

> [**6.3.3.  202 Accepted**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.3.3)
>
> The `202` (Accepted) status code indicates that the request has been accepted for processing, but the processing has not been completed. The request might or might not eventually be acted upon, as it might be disallowed when processing actually takes place.  There is no facility in HTTP for re-sending a status code from an asynchronous operation.
>
> The `202` response is intentionally noncommittal.  Its purpose is to allow a server to accept a request for some other process (perhaps a batch-oriented process that is only run once per day) without requiring that the user agent's connection to the server persist until the process is completed.  The representation sent with this response ought to describe the request's current status and point to (or embed) a status monitor that can provide the user with an estimate of when the request will be fulfilled.

Comment: Thank you very much, this makes sense. I got caught up in futures and didn't realize I could just do it so plainly.